# Finding all identifiers containing part of the token

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

I know I can get a string from resources using

`Resources.GetIdentifier(token, "string", ctx.ApplicationContext.PackageName)`

(sorry, this is in C#, it's part of a Xamarin.Android project).

I know that if my elements are called foo_1, foo_2, foo_3, then I can iterate and grab the strings using something like

```
var myList = new List<string>();
for(var i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
{
     var id = AppContent.GetIdentifier(token + i.ToString(), "string", "package_name");
     if (id != 0)
        myList.Add(AppContext.GetString(id));
}
```

My issue is that my token names all begin with "posn." (the posn can denote the position of anything, so you can have "posn.left_arm" and "posn.brokenose"). I want to be able to add to the list of posn elements, so I can't really store a list of the parts after the period. I can't use a string-array for this either (specific reason means I can't do this).

Is there a way that I can use something akin to "posn.*" in the getidentifer call to return the ids?

Comment: What is `AppContent` and does it have a method that allows you to get **all** identifiers? If so, then you could just get all of them and do a filter on them using Linq Where.

Comment: Sorry, that should be AppContext. I'm thinking of using XmlReader to read the strings file, extract anything with posn in the element name and getting the ids of these... such fun when there isn't anything provided ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use some reflection foo to get what you want. It is not pretty at all but it works. The reflection stuff is based on https://gist.github.com/atsushieno/4e66da6e492dfb6c1dd0

```
private List<string> _stringNames;
private IEnumerable<int> GetIdentifiers(string contains)
{
    if (_stringNames == null)
    {
        var eass = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        Func<Assembly, Type> f = ass =>
            ass.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ResourceDesignerAttribute), true)
                .OfType<ResourceDesignerAttribute>()
                .Where(ca => ca.IsApplication)
                .Select(ca => ass.GetType(ca.FullName))
                .FirstOrDefault(ty => ty != null);

        var t = f(eass) ??
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().Select(ass => f(ass)).FirstOrDefault(ty => ty != null);

        if (t != null)
        {
            var strings = t.GetNestedTypes().FirstOrDefault(n => n.Name == "String");

            if (strings != null)
            {
                var fields = strings.GetFields();
                _stringNames = new List<string>();
                foreach (var field in fields)
                {
                    _stringNames.Add(field.Name);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (_stringNames != null)
    {
        var names = _stringNames.Where(s => s.Contains(contains));
        foreach (var name in names)
        {
            yield return Resources.GetIdentifier(name, "string", ComponentName.PackageName);
        }
    }
}
```

Then somewhere in your `Activity` you could do:

```
var ids = GetIdentifiers("action").ToList();
```

That will give you all the `String` Resources, which contain the string `action`.

Comment: Thanks for that - certainly does the job. I can up with a hack solution which works. Add a <string name="foo.start></string> and <string name="foo.end"></string> surrounding the list to be read. Then  var package = ctx.ApplicationContext.PackageName; var stringList = new List<string>(); for (var l = ctx.Resources.GetIdentifier(token + ".start", "string", package);l < ctx.Resources.GetIdentifier(token + ".end", "string", package);  ++l) { var str = ctx.Resources.GetString(l);  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))  stringList.Add(str);  } return stringList; - a hack, but it works. Yours is better :)